# Expected identifier, string or number

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have an object like;

```
var defaults = {
        id: 'ActionSlider',
        element: '',
        closeBtnWidth: 55,
        panelWidth: 320,
        class: '',
        css: {},
        create: function() {},
    },
```

and when i run my page in IE8 standards its giving me the following error;

**SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number**

and points to the line : class:' ',

can anyone please tell me why i cant use this for IE?
is it a reserved word or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add quotes round the `class` which is a reserved word. Please also note, that you should remove the last comma:

```
var defaults = {
        id: 'ActionSlider',
        element: '',
        closeBtnWidth: 55,
        panelWidth: 320,
        "class": '',
        css: {},
        create: function() {}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep, `class` is a reserved word. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words)

Answer (score 0):

`class` is [reserved words](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm) in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Usually class refers to the class attribute of any object like `<div >`, `<input >` etc. which shows displays class as `<div class="someclass">`