# jQuery Dynamic Element Error in IE7/8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

When creating dynamic elements in jQuery 1.7.2, I found that this code works fine in Safari, Chrome, Firefox, and IE9/10. However, in IE7/8 this code yields this error message:

`SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number`

Here is the element creation code:

```
$("<span></span>", {
    text: "Please Specify: ",
    class: $(this).attr("id")+"other" <-- error points here
});
```

Why is declaring a class causing this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because in ECMAScript3 (current supported version is ES5), "class" is a reserved word, you must add quotes around property name `class` for it to be IE7/8 compliant. Adding quotes fixes the issue and the code now works in every browser I have tested.

```
$("<span></span>", {
    text: "Please Specify: ",
    'class': $(this).attr("id")+"other"
});
```

Comment: please elaborate on downvote?! If it is because of duplicate, please tell us

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14702524/1414562

Comment: I'd keep it for google since it has more keywords in it.

Comment: This is a silly oversight question, and a duplicate.